# How to use content negotation format parameter in Spring WebFlux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

```
spring.mvc.contentnegotiation.favor-parameter=true
spring.mvc.contentnegotiation.parameter-name=format
```

How can I use the content negotiation feature in spring `webflux`?

So that `/request?format=json` is possible beside `Accept` header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as follows, but don't know it that's the correct way:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class ReactiveWebFluxConfigurer {
    @Value("${spring.mvc.contentnegotiation.parameter-name}")
    private String formatName;

    @Bean
    public WebFluxConfigurer webFluxConfigurer() {
        return new WebFluxConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void configureContentTypeResolver(RequestedContentTypeResolverBuilder builder) {
                builder.parameterResolver().parameterName(formatName);

                //if you want, add additional fallback to Accept header if format param is missing
                builder.headerResolver();
            }
        };
    }
}
```